# SQL Server - Command Line utility for exporting and importing of entire database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, import, sql-server-2008-r2, export

I am looking for a command line utility to export and import an entire SQL Server database. I am looking to automate the process of moving data from source database to destination database given the credentials.

This would be similar to exp and imp command for Oracle.

I have already looked at Bcp and SS import export wizard.

Would someone point to any such utility?

Comment: Maybe you could use SQL log shipping, check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server

Comment: The [help/on-topic] says very clearly *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: @KenWhite - I apologize -- will take care from next time onwards, and will remove this question

Comment: sqlpackage.exe is a command-line tool included with SQL Server Data Tools that can create a BACPAC containing schema and data.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found one if it exists. I typically script up a power shell function like this one to serve the purpose.

[export with power shell](https://gist.github.com/cheynewallace/9558179)

You can then call the script from the command prompt and even add parameters to export by table, database etc.